# Is there any Java based open source framework to find values from a text field based on key string with delimiter?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, machine-learning, text-mining

Is there any Java based open source framework to find values in a text field based on key string with delimiter?

Example:

Key: username 
Start-Delimiter: ; 
End-Delimiter: ;

Key: on 
Start-Delimiter: ; 
End-Delimiter: ;

Sample Input: A user with username ;surenraju; logged into the system on ;Thu May 2, 2013 2:30pm;

Results: 
username -  surenraju
on - Thu May 2, 2013 2:30pm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sample input seems to contradict "key" example.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your response. I have edited the question. Is the question clear now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's more clear now.

Comment: Your Question and example don't match.

Input : `A user with username ;surenraju; logged into the system on ;Thu May 2, 2013 2:30pm;`

would mean

Output : 

    `A user with username -> surenraju`
    `logged into the system on -> Thu May 2, 2013 2:30pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this problem with Regex.

Sample code:

```
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    keys.add("username");
    keys.add("on");
    String startDelimiter = ":";
    String endDelimiter = ":";
    String searchStr = "A user with username :suren: logged into the system on :22 May 2013 2:30 PM:";
    for (String key : keys) {
        String pattern = "("+key+")[ ]*?"+startDelimiter+"([^" +endDelimiter+ "]+)"+endDelimiter;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(searchStr);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + m.group(1) + " Value: "
                    + m.group(2));
        }
    }
```

Tests

I. Key: username Start-Delimiter: ; End-Delimiter: ;

Need to find a value which if followed by key( in this case username ) and value is between start and end delimiters(in this case ;).

II. Key: on Start-Delimiter: ; End-Delimiter: ;

Sample Input:

A user with username ;suren; logged into the system on ;Thu May 2, 2013 2:30pm;

Results: I. username - suren II. on - Thu May 2, 2013 2:30pm